# OpenJDK- type like NULLType

Tags: java

**Problem:** I want to modified `javac` compiler such that we have a special internal type, who called `MyType` internally and only one expression `mexp`- instance of this type which "instance of" all reference type. I.e. i want to add analog of `NullType` and `null` expression. Does there exist tutorial about this? But i cant find where we create `null` expression in the sources. And where is implementation of `NullType`?

I have, moreover one question.

In the package `javax.lang.model.type` we have description of interface `NullType` which inherited from interface `RefernceType`.

**Question** As i understand this is a reason of the NullType is subtype of all reference type. But in the package `javax.lang.model.type`we have descriptionof interface `WildcardType`, who doesnt inherited from the `RefernceType`. Hence `WildcardType` doesnt a parent of `NullType`. It confusing, because in `List<? extends Integer> ints;` we can add `null` to `ints`.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Can't you just make your `MyType` a singleton object?

Comment: What is it that you're really trying to do here?  What has necessitated this?

Comment: @tobias_k I have no specific problem. It's for experiment only.

Comment: In that case, I think we can safely say that there's (probably) no tutorial on how to hack the compiler to add something like this.  If you did this, your modified javac wouldn't actually be a java compiler anymore (it would compile a superset of java), so it's rather outside the domain of what Java programmers would typically do.  If you decide to carry out your experiment, good luck.

Comment: @Ian McLaird Maybe you can answer my question: I dont understand where compiler created `null` expression. I can find description of `NullType` Interface only.

Comment: No idea.  I know next to nothing about the internals of the java compiler.